# Deleting a row for the second time in a datagrid view is not working

Tags: vb6

I have a list of data from a database displayed in a datagrid view. Whenever I delete one record, it successfully deletes it from the table and also in the database but when I try to delete another record, the delete function doesn't work anymore.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub cmdDelete_Click()
    Set Connect = New Class1
    Set rxdelete = New ADODB.Recordset

    Dim sqlString, dataID, answer As String

    dataID = lblID.Caption
    sqlString = "DELETE FROM tblloan WHERE ID = '" & Trim$(dataID) & "'"

    answer = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete this record?", vbYesNo, "RheaLending")

    If answer = vbYes Then
        rxdelete.Open sqlString, con, 3, 3
        Call refreshList
    Else
        Call refreshList
    End If

End Sub
```

Here is the code for `refreshList`:

```
Sub refreshList()

    Set Connect = New Class1
    Set rxloan = New ADODB.Recordset

    rxloan.Open "SELECT * FROM tblloan LIMIT 100", con, 3, 3
    lblLNumberRecords.Caption = Format(rxloan.RecordCount, "###,###,###.##")
    Set DatLoans.DataSource = rxloan
    DatLoans.SetFocus

End Sub
```

Please somebody help me! 
I am using vb6, adodb and mysql database.

Comment: "Doesn't work anymore" What happens? Did your try to step through the code with a debugger?

Comment: You delete record with ID taken from lblID component, which seems to be a label. I think it is not correctly refreshed and  contains wrong value after the deletion

Comment: Yes, I did. Actually i have another table for clients and also have delete button there, it works perfectly and the codes were the same. @Robert Kock

Comment: As @EddiGordo mentioned, I suspect your `dataID` value doesn't get updated to the ID of the new record you are trying to delete. Add a breakpoint and check what `dataID` is in `sqlString`.

Comment: the label display the data's id to be deleted. i simply store it in dataID variable to make it as a reference.

Comment: I found the problem @EddiGordo. You were right, the data was not refereshed correctly. thank you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your delete statement does not return a result set other than the number of records deleted. use an adodb.command instead of a .recordset. another thing is you are not killing your objects  it can cause you greef in the long run because the app can slow down.

```
Set rxdelete = New ADODB.command
set rxdelete.currentconneciton = [your connection object]
rxdelete.commandtext =  "DELETE FROM tblloan WHERE ID = '" &   Trim$(dataID) & "'"
rxdelete.execute 

'at the bottom of your sub

set rxdelete=nothing
set connect = nothing
```